# How to run VBA macro using AppleScript?

Tags: applescript, ms-office

To run VBA macros stored in Personal.xlsb, I have to:

1. Tool - macros (I use menu bar search for this)
2. In the macro dialog box, I have to go to the end of xlsb! and type the name of subroutine (have to type exactly -- this is time-consuming step)
3. click on run to execute

Is there a better way of doing it via Applescript? I got the following -- is this recommended or feasible?

```
tell application "Microsoft Word"
run VB macro macro name "page_number"
end tell
```

The alternative is to transform VBA code of "page_number" to AppleScript itself. But the Excel dictionary is not well defined or easy to figure out. Wish there was a tool to do automatic conversion :) Or how do I launch a VBA macro more easily?

Comment: I had luck using this but yeah it requires an existing macro, I want to find a way to create a macro too and/or just run free form VBA embedded in AppleScript